# Rich textbox that displays html like a web browser control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, richtextbox

I am displaying text in a rich textbox and i want it to show the html formatting on the text. Is there a way to make a rich textbox display html.

**If you push the button on the following link you will see how my out put displays, i would like it done in a rich textbox.**

http://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html

Is there a way to build a rich textbox that can display html???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RTF encoding` is different from `HTML`.

If not, then you need to write your own HTML to RTF converter or find something similar.

[Writing Your Own RTF Converter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter). This guy gives a great breakdown of how the program works along with details of the conversion.

An [Extended richtextbox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12172/An-extended-RichTextBox-to-save-and-load-quot-HTML) control, Check this out. It may solve your solution

Comment: I don't want to use a webBrowser there are to many problems with the scroll bars, and i don't to display the text, i want to have the html formatting.

Comment: So this RTF converter will it display the text with the highlighted formatting i showed in my link?

Comment: @Pomster, check my updated answer and extended ricttextbox control

Comment: Just reading though what to do and add. those are both very big links :)

Comment: It is to much i can have that whole class, and i can find any formatting for the strike out and highlighting.